# Div shortens when padding is removed

Tags: html, css

I have a row of divs that each contain one image. The image `height` is set to `100%` for each image and each `div` has a `padding-left` of `20px`, except for the last div which has no padding. Because the last div does not have padding and the `img` `width` is set to `100%`, the last image appears taller than the other images. I would like to fix this but I am not sure how.

Here is a **[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sknf7/)** that shows a visual representation of the problem.

HTML :

```
 <div class="grid">
        <div class="col-1-4">
            <img src="" />
        </div>
        <div class="col-1-4">
            <img src="" />
        </div>
        <div class="col-1-4">
            <img src="" />
        </div>
        <div class="col-1-4">
            <img src="" />
        </div>
    </div>
```

CSS :

```
 img {
        width: 100%;

    }

    *, *:after, *:before {
        -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
        -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
        box-sizing: border-box;
    }

    body {
        margin: 0px;
    }

    [class*='col-'] {
        float: left;
        padding-right: 20px;
    }

    [class*='col-']:last-of-type {
        padding-right: 0px;
    }

    .grid {
        width: 100%;
        max-width: 940px;
        min-width: 755px;
        margin: 0 auto;
        overflow: hidden;
    }

    .grid:after {
        content: "";
        display: table;
        clear: both;
    }

    .col-1-4 {
        width: 25%;
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd switch to a (percentage-based) margin for your gutters, like so:

```css
[class*='col-'] {
    float: left;
    margin-right: 4%;
}

[class*='col-']:last-of-type {
    margin-right: 0;
}

.col-1-4 {
    width: 22%;
}
```

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/sknf7/3/

Answer (score 1):

You have this in your CSS

```
-webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
-moz-box-sizing: border-box;
box-sizing: border-box;
```

`border-box` means the size of an element is its height/width and its padding. So if your image is 100px tall with 10px padding at top and bottom, it'll only show as 80px tall. This is what's causing your issue.

The alternative is `content-box`, where the padding is added on to the height or width. So 100px + 10px padding top and bottom would be 120px tall instead.

One way to fix it is make the divs content-box, and slightly narrow as a result (to compensate for increased padding width).

```
[class*='col-'] {
    box-sizing: content-box;
    -moz-box-sizing:content-box;
}
.col-1-4 {
    width: 23%;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It's because you use `box-sizing: border-box;`, you can either remove this or use margin instead of padding. (either way you need to adjust your grid)

border box removed:

http://jsfiddle.net/sknf7/1/

margin instead of padding:

http://jsfiddle.net/sknf7/2/

Answer (score 0):

Paul's answer certainly works, however you may want to consider improving the compatibility of/shortening your CSS by re-working this a bit. Those *col wildcard selectors won't work in IE8 or earlier

```
.col-1-4 {
    width: 22%;
    margin-right: 4%;
    float: left;
}

.col-1-4:last-child
{
    margin-right: 0;   
}
```

The above would get you the same effect